# About Unity A* (Astar) Pathfinding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, a-star

I apologize if I irritate you as I am still very new to programming programming.
I am currently learning to work with Astar Pathfinding in Unity.
I am also currently referencing code for several Astar algorithms, many of which also introduce map generation code.

This question is about that map generation code, but I would appreciate it if you could answer it in connection with Astar Pathfinding, if possible.

The following code is introduced by a Japanese programmer.
I have a question about "public static Coord operator +(Coord a, Coord b) {return new Coord(a.x +a.y, b.x + b.y); }" in public struct Coord in the following code.

What do the "a and b" in a.x and b.x mean?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class AStarGrid
{
    public enum GroundType
    {
        NotRoad,
        Road,
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 座標
    /// </summary>
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct Coord
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public static Coord zero = new Coord(){ x = 0, y = 0 };
        public static Coord one = new Coord(){ x = 1, y = 1 };
        public static Coord left = new Coord(){ x = -1, y = 0 };
        public static Coord up = new Coord(){ x = 0, y = 1 };
        public static Coord right = new Coord(){ x = 1, y = 0 };
        public static Coord down = new Coord(){ x = 0, y = -1 };

        public static Coord operator +(Coord a, Coord b)
            { return new Coord(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y); }
        public static Coord operator -(Coord a, Coord b)
            { return new Coord(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y); }

        public float SqrMagnitude { get { return x * x + y * y; } }
        public float Magnitude { get { return Mathf.Sqrt(SqrMagnitude); } }

        public Coord(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = x;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cell
    /// </summary>
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Cell
    {
        public Coord coord;
        public GroundType groundType;
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private List<Cell> _cells;
    public List<Cell> Cells { get { return _cells; } }
    [SerializeField]
    private int _columnCount;
    public int ColumnCount { get { return _columnCount; } }
    [SerializeField]
    private int _rowCount;
    public int RowCount { get { return _rowCount; } }
    [SerializeField]
    private Coord _startCellCoord;
    public Cell StartCell { get { return GetCell(_startCellCoord); } set { _startCellCoord = value.coord; } }
    [SerializeField]
    private Coord _goalCellCoord;
    public Cell GoalCell { get { return GetCell(_goalCellCoord); } set { _goalCellCoord = value.coord; } }

    public AStarGrid(int columnCount, int rowCount)
    {
        _columnCount = columnCount;
        _rowCount = rowCount;
        _cells = new List<Cell>();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount * rowCount; i++) {
            var column = Mathf.FloorToInt(i / rowCount);
            var row = i % rowCount;
            var coord = new Coord(){ x = column, y = row };
            _cells.Add(new Cell(){ coord = coord });
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// get cell
    /// </summary>
    public Cell GetCell(Coord coord){
        return GetCell(coord.x, coord.y);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// get cell
    /// </summary>
    public Cell GetCell(int x, int y)
    {
        if (IsValidCoord(x, y)) {
            var index = x * _rowCount + y;
            return _cells[index];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does the cell exist?
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsValidCoord(int x, int y)
    {
        return x >= 0 && x < _columnCount && y >= 0 && y < _rowCount;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// get neighbor cells
    /// </summary>
    public List<Cell> GetAdjacences(int x, int y)
    {
        var adjacences = new List<Cell>();
        var offsets = new Coord[] { Coord.left, Coord.up, Coord.right, Coord.down };
        for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Length; i++) {
            var cell = GetCell(x + offsets[i].x, y + offsets[i].y);
            if (cell != null) {
                adjacences.Add(cell);
            }
        }
        return adjacences;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a and b are references to instances of Cord struct witch contains x and y variables witch you have access to by using . After name of instance of a class/struct also these a and b means if u use - between two cords it will do the math of x of a minus x of b and so on

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I should understand operator overload first.

Comment: Yes @Semapho , the two operands that are participating are getting "names" here: `...operator +(Coord a, Coord b)`, could also have been `c0` and `c1` instead of `a` and `b`